# Localization of a regular local ring is regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Quoting Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

> **Definition.** We say a scheme $X$ is regular in codimension one if every local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$ of $X$ of dimension one is regular.
>
> The most important examples of such schemes are nonsingular varieties
> over a field (I, §5) and noetherian normal schemes. On a nonsingular variety the local ring of every closed point is regular (I, 5.1), hence all the
> local rings are regular, **since they are localizations of the local rings of
> closed points.**

I know that there is a general result stating that localizations at prime ideals of regular local rings are regular (Cor. 2.13 [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/caag1/jayanthan.pdf)). I was wondering if all this machinery is really needed to prove something that Hartshorne says so easily; is not there an easier proof for this case?

My idea is that the following result would be enough

> Let $A$ be a (noetherian) regular local ring. If $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ is a prime ideal such that $\dim(A_{\mathfrak{p}})=1$ then $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is regular.

How to prove this last statement? What do you think Hartshorne was actually meaning in his assertion?

Comment: Theorem 2.18 on page 125 of Shafarevich's book may be relevant.